# How to use firebasedynamiclinks for get short link for google drive files using google apps script?

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, deprecated, firebase-dynamic-links, url-shortener

Please say how to use firebase dynamic links for get short link for google drive files using google apps script.

Before I was use urlshortner to generate short link for google drive files.

Now UrlShortner is deprecated, please give solution for using firebase dynamic link in google apps script.

I enabled firebase api in google cloud console, after I don't know how to use  firebase dynamic link.

Comment: Have you looked at the REST API docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest - that would be the method I'd use to create a link.

Comment: Tente isso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63604093/firebase-short-urls-not-redirecting