# Firebase short URLs not redirecting

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, firebase-dynamic-links

I created a Google Sheet that uses a Google Script to generate short URLs via Firebase API.

This is the code in the Google Script

```
function URLShortener(longURL) {
  var body = {
    "dynamicLinkInfo": {
      "domainUriPrefix": "https://go.example.com",
      "link" : longURL
    },
    "suffix": {
      "option": "SHORT"
    }
  };
  var key = 'xxxxxxx'
  var url = "https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=" + key;
  var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    "contentType": "application/json",
    'payload': JSON.stringify(body),
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var obj = data["shortLink"];
  return obj;
  Logger.log(obj)
}
```

The script works and it generates URLs similar to https://go.example.com/Xdka but these link redirect to https://example.com/Xdka instead of the actual URL that is sent, e.g. https://example.com/final_url.

If I try to generate these short links from the Firebase dashboard the same happens.

Did I misunderstand how these short URLs work or am I missing something?

Comment: just a ping to surface this again